# Movie with a character un-frozen after several attempts and living in a future where everyone else is eternally youthful

Tags: story-identification, movie, cryogenics

I'm trying to find a movie that I watched about a year ago. It was from Redbox, so surely not new at that time, but maybe a 2010-2020 (certainly not older than 2000).

The movie was about a man, I think very wealthy, who had a terminal illness and froze himself cryogenically in hopes that he could be revived at a time when there was a cure. The movie possibly opens with the extended surgery scene of him being brought back with many specialists working in fairly realistic, albeit advanced, ways to bring him to life again. It was clearly a very costly endeavor and was being sponsored by some kind of corporation which wanted to demonstrate the technology. The corporation turns out to be fairly sinister.

It turns out that he was not, in fact, the first person to have this procedure, merely the first to have survived (the 2? others having been covered up).

Everyone in this world is apparently eternally youthful and the character brought back is something of a freak for having gone through the normal (to us) aging process.

By the end the character figures things out and I think kills himself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [Realive](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4074928/) (2016).

> Marc will die of cancer and chooses cryogenic freeze and hopes to be
> thawed, when there's a solution to his condition. He's the first human
> brought back 68 years later. Can he adapt mentally and physically?

Comment: That's it. I recognize the shiny white look.

Comment: @Charles - I haven't seen this one before. It reminded me of Eva (2011) and Open Your Eyes (1997)

Comment: It is a bit like Eva. Haven’t seen the other one.